# SiteMapProvider doesn't work on the server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvcsitemapprovider

I'm working with ASP.NET MVC and I use DevExpress.
I created a menu with MvcSiteMapProvider. It works just as I want while debugging. But when I deploy it to the server it just prints the Strings from the Xml-File.
I checked the File-System of the server and it says that everything needed is deployed. (The Package & the xml-File).

Does somebody know what I forgot?
Or what I do wrong?

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: No. It just prints the strings, that are in the xml-file. For example:
<mvcSiteMapNode title="TitleString" controller="ControllerString" action="Index" /> results as "TitleString_ControllerString_Index"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that you haven't deployed your HTML helper templates. Be sure you copy over the contents of the `/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/` directory to your server.